# If size of the physical memory is 2^32-1, then what is the size of virtual memory?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I know that physical address will be 32 bits long but how do I find out the size of virtual memory by this information?

Comment: Virtual memory is stored on disk and can be any size.

Comment: Total virtual memory space depends on the architecture (and OS). It's unrelated to physical memory size. If you mean swap space, that is also unrelated to physical memory size.

Answer (score 4):

The total size of the virtual memory address space is 2^32 on `x86` architecture and much larger (currently around 2^48) on `x64` architecture . However, the OS usually reserves a portion of this space, so a 32 bit app can't necessarily address 4GB at once. Also, the OS can easily swap different pieces of memory in and out, so if necessary, more than 4GB could be supported with assistance of the OS through a form of bank switching by telling it to modify your page tables when you want to access memory that isn't currently mapped into your address space.

Also, the maximum amount of physical memory supported is not necessarily 2^32. Even 32bit machines often support up to 2^36 through PSE36 or PAE.

Comment: virtual memory is greater than physical memory so shouldn't the size of virtual memory be greater that 2^32 ?

Comment: No, virtual memory isn't necessarily greater than phyiscal memory.

Comment: It is given that the the size of physical memory is 2^32 - 1, we have to find the size of virtual memory by this information.

Comment: Is that a homework question? Just regurgitate whatever the professor wants. It doesn't have any bearing on the real world.

Comment: no, its not a homework question, it was asked in a job interview.

Comment: It's possible that the answer they want is "you can't". Just talk for a while about stuff like paging and PAE and they'll probably be impressed.

Comment: @Antimony a quick sanity check.....if i am saying that the architecture is 32 bit then the reg size is 32 bit right? or does it put any restrictions on the size of address bus? cause i generally read that 32 bit PCs can support upto 4G RAM....is that just a coincidence? a counter example would be the 8086 which is 16 bit but with 20 address lines.

Answer (score 0):

The size of virtual memory can't be determined by just giving the size of physical memory.