# OPERATING SYSTEMS: what is the size of the virtual memory?

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual

LINK 1: [If size of the physical memory is 2^32-1, then what is the size of virtual memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809294/if-size-of-the-physical-memory-is-232-1-then-what-is-the-size-of-virtual-memorK)

the above link gives me an answer but i still do have some doubts.
pls answer in the way the questions posted here so that i will not be confused.....

```
1.Virtual memory is also called as Demand Paging whenever a page fault occurs 
  the operating system swaps the required page from the virtual memory. the virtual memory
  here mean the harddisk or secondary storage. So how much space can be allocated for a
  porcess in virutal memory? can this size(the space allocated for each process in the 
  Virtual memory) exceeds the size of our RAM size? i mean if our RAM is 4GB then what is 
  the maximum size of the virtual memory you can have for a process?can we have 4GB of 
  virtual memory for every process or can we have more than 4GB for every process?
   (if it needs)


2.is the Virtual memory size fixed or dynamic? How much space is allocated for this memory
  and in the above link it is told that 2^48 is the size of virtual memory in 64 bit machine
  why is it only 2^48 and how can once can say a number like that?
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If size of the physical memory is 2^32-1, then what is the size of virtual memory?

The size of the virtual address space is independent of the size of the physical address space. There is no answer.

> So how much space can be allocated for a porcess in virutal memory?

That depends upon hardware limits, system parameters, and process quotas.

> can this size(the space allocated for each process in the   Virtual memory) exceeds the size of our RAM size?

Yes and it frequently does.

> i mean if our RAM is 4GB then what is   the maximum size of the virtual memory you can have for a process?

It can be anything. The rams size does not control.

> can we have 4GB of   virtual memory for every process or can we have more than 4GB for every process?

Both

> is the Virtual memory size fixed or dynamic?

Dynamic

> How much space is allocated for this memory   and in the above link it is told that 2^48 is the size of virtual memory in 64 bit machine   why is it only 2^48 and how can once can say a number like that?

It could be a hardware limit for a specific processor.

Answer (score 0):

Paging is the way that virtual addresses are converted into physical addresses. This is done via page tables.

On x86 in Long Mode (64 bit mode), the page tables allow for 48 bit virtual address spaces (as in, 2^48 max size). This limitation is due to the design of x86's long mode page tables. Paging uses a few bits at a time from pointers to determine where to go next in the page tables. Basically, page tables are a relatively shallow b-tree style tree that let you look up the physical address corresponding to a virtual address.

To convert virtual addresses to physical addresses Long Mode page tables (for small pages) first extract 9 bits from the virtual address, then 9 more, then 9 more, then 9 more to find the right page, and use the low 12 bits to find the precise byte being accessed, for 48 bits total.

(For large and huge pages, x86 skips the last 1 and 2 steps of paging respectively, to find the address of the large or huge page, and the unused low 21 or 30 bits are used to find the precise byte in that page)

Virtual address spaces aren't necessarily dynamic, depending on what is meant by dynamic. The address space is always 48 bits (so long as you aren't switching between modes, like from long mode to protected mode with paging enabled (I.e. 32 bit mode)). Virtual address spaces are almost always sparse, as in most canonical (valid) addresses don't point don't point anything useful. The page tables don't have mappings for most addresses (accesses to those addresses generate page faults, which on Linux are often bounced back to userspace as the SIGSEGV you know and love).

That said, virtual memory can be dynamic in that when a page fault occurs the kernel could map in that page. To implement swap, OSes will use extra space on disk to give the illusion of more RAM by writing infrequently used pages back to disk, and lazily pulling pages back into RAM.

Fun fact, page tables have no restriction preventing the same physical page from being mapped in multiple times. You could build a monstrous page table with every virtual address pointing into exactly the same page (which is crazy), but doable. This means address spaces aren't necessarily sparse, just very likely to be. (Note that this page table would be huge. I'm sure someone has done the calculation, but my first guess would be order of terabytes)

Comment: For the pedants that probably don't exist, virtual address aren't a thing in x86 nomenclature. Instead there are logical and linear addresses. Logical being pre-segmentation, linear being pre-paging. Segmentation isn't all that exciting in long mode, but it's still a thing.